# Android N Java8 java.time

Tags: android, java-8, java-time, android-7.0-nougat

I updated to the latest Android N sdk.  The only thing I don't understand is why I cannot import `java.time` into my code?  I thought Java8 is available through Android N.  Then why didn't Google add `java.time` package?

Comment: just waiting is an option: jack is now deprecated and java8 API will soon be supported directly: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html

Comment: @ccpizza They do not support all features of Java 8 for Android.

Comment: Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for Android in the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36000997/642706) project; see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Android N is not supporting all the features of Java 8.
Following features are only supported:

- Default and static interface methods
- Lambda expressions
- Repeatable annotations

Reflection and language-related APIs:

- `java.lang.FunctionalInterface`
- `java.lang.annotation.Repeatable`
- `java.lang.reflect.Method.isDefault()`

and Reflection APIs associated with repeatable annotations, such as 
`AnnotatedElement.getAnnotationsByType(Class)`

Utility APIs:

- `java.util.function`

For more info check the following link: http://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html

Comment: Thanks for the outline.  I guess our only option for Java 8 Time api is https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP

Comment: @Igor right untill stable version of android-n will release. hope in stable version they will support

Comment: Well, if they didn't add the Time api yet, then they probably won't in Android N.  Otherwise, I have no idea how Google makes decisions to include or omit certain apis...

Comment: Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for Android in the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36000997/642706) project; see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 29):

`java.time` package was added only in API 26 (Android O):
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary.html

**UPDATE**

Starting with version 4.0 of the Android Gradle Plugin, you can use a subset of `java.time` APIs (along with a number of other Java 8 language APIs) **without** requiring a minimum API level for your app: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring

> The following set of APIs are supported when building your app using Android Gradle plugin 4.0.0 or higher:
>
> - Sequential streams (`java.util.stream`)
> - A subset of `java.time`
> - `java.util.function`
> - Recent additions to `java.util.{Map,Collection,Comparator}`
> - Optionals (`java.util.Optional`, `java.util.OptionalInt` and `java.util.OptionalDouble`) and some other new classes useful with the
>   above APIs
> - Some additions to `java.util.concurrent.atomic` (new methods on `AtomicInteger`, `AtomicLong` and `AtomicReference`)
> - `ConcurrentHashMap` (with bug fixes for Android 5.0)

To enable support for these language APIs, one needs to include the following lines `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    // Required when setting minSdkVersion to 20 or lower
    multiDexEnabled true
  }

  compileOptions {
    // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}

dependencies {
  coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.4'
}
```

Answer (score 19):

There is backport library of `java.time` APIs for Android that can be used

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP

Comment: This library is no longer maintained, deprecated, and the repo is now archived. You should now [use Gradle 4.00 + desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#j8-desugar)

Answer (score 6):

Starting from Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0, we can finally use proper `java.time` package classes without worries (almost):
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

`Optional, java.time, streams`, and more are desugared into Java 7 by the Android Gradle Plugin.

To add those classes support, you just need to add a few lines to your build file:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    // Required when setting minSdkVersion to 20 or lower
    multiDexEnabled true
  }

  compileOptions {
    // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}

dependencies {
  coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9'
}
```

Here is the full list: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table

Comment: Why do we need desugaring if we're using Kotlin?

Comment: Kotlin still uses many Java classes underneath and, I guess, they couldn't just reimplement the java.time package in order to sustain the backwards compatibility?