# Java 8 Stream API in Android N

Tags: java, android, lambda, android-7.0-nougat

According to [Google's introduction](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2016/03/first-preview-of-android-n-developer.html), starting with Android N, the Android API is supposed to support Java streams.

However, using the Android N preview SDK, I am unable to use any of the Stream APIs in my project (which is configured with Android N as minimum, target and build SDK version).

The `java.util.stream` package seems to be missing, as are the `stream()` methods of all collection implementations I've tried.

Are the necessary classes not yet included in the current preview release of the SDK?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000997/android-n-java8-java-time  All features of Java 8 are not supported there are some of the features are only supported in preview.

Comment: So the Android developers blog post is incorrect? It explicitly states that "default and static methods, streams, and functional interfaces -- are also now available on N and above".

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/preview/j8-jack.html this is as per the developer document.

Comment: The stream API is not a Java 8 language feature (which are implemented by the new Jack compiler and available to earlier Android targets). It would be provided as a set of interfaces and implementation classes in the Android SDK.

Comment: `java.util.stream` also does not appear in the offline JavaDocs for the N Developer Preview 1. Between that and your experiences, it would appear that `java.util.stream` did not "make the cut". Whether this is a bug in the description or a bug in the SDK proper is unclear to me.

Comment: The "Java 8" support is not part of Android N - it will be supported with all versions starting from Gingerbread. Apparently this would be a feature of a new Jack compiler. So, until Jack compiler is released I would not expect anything.

Comment: Please distinguish between Java language, bytecode and library features. Jack (which is already available and works fine, by the way), for example, compiles Lambdas in a way that is backwards-compatible with older versions of Dalvik. (The "real" JDK, for comparison, implements them using Java 7 bytecode features – invokedynamic – and Java 8 classes – LambdaMetafactory.) Streams, on the other hand, are a library feature even on android, and will only be available to N+.

Comment: Oh, I see - perhaps I was expecting too much magic from Jack. Something like packing those libraries into the app.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not yet in the current preview, but it has already been merged into the AOSP Git master. See here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/916b0af2ccdd1bdfc0283b1096b291c40997d05f

**EDIT:**

Just to avoid possible confusion: in March 2016, when this question has been asked by the OP, Android N developer `preview-1` was the only publicly available build of what is now known as Android 7.0 "Nougat".

The `preview-1` build did in fact not include the Java 8 Stream API, but it was added shortly after (one month later) in the developer `preview-2` build.

So, Android 7.0 API level 24 **does** support the Java 8 Stream API now.

Comment: Please update your answer - Stream API is included in latest revision of Android 7.0 SDK Platform (API 24).