# Converting a string into date format

Tags: java, android

I'm adding an event, the event displays starting hour (hh:mm) and ending hour (hh:mm), there are 2 tiemPickers, one to pick starting time and one for duration.

**Problem 1:**

If the user picks the starting time to be at 10:30h and duration of 1:40h, the ending time should be 12:10h instead of 11:70h, how do I do this?

**Problem 2:**

If the user picks starting time of 23:00h and duration of 02:00h, ending time should be 01:00h instead of 25:00h.

**What I have:**

```
// getting the selected time
int endingHourInt = prefs.getInt("mDurationHour", 0) + prefs.getInt("mStartingHour",0);
int endingMinInt = prefs.getInt("mDurationMin", 0) + prefs.getInt("mStartingMin",0);

// displaying the text
endingTime.setText(endingHourInt + ":" + endingMinInt );
```

Comment: Use java.util.Date class and getTime(). If you use Android-N then java.time classes are better.

Comment: I'd make a new date from endingHour and endingMinute and format the date as I like it

Comment: Isn't it easier to use existing classes instead of ints. You can do all these kind of calculations automatically with the time in the `Date` class..

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000997

Comment: I think the duplicate would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015536/java-how-to-add-10-mins-in-my-time

Comment: @JonSkeet didn't aware about this (didn't have a close look at Java8 support on Android), bad news...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(endingHourInt,Calendar.HOUR);
calendar.set(endingMinInt,Calendaur.MINTUE);
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
format.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: You forget that OP wants to add a time to his current time. So I would add a `calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);` to make your answer more complete.