# How to convert "2017-04-26T20:55:00.000Z" string to a Date in java android studio

Tags: java, android, date-formatting

I am new to android studio and java development.

I would like to parse this date:

```
"2017-04-26T20:55:00.000Z"
```

, which I am getting from a hash map string.

I would like to display only the date on my view.

Comment: Please clarify if you'd like to create an instance of Date class from a string? Or just modify the string to only keep the date part of it? There are 2 parts to your question as it seems to be: "How to create an instance of Date from a string?" and "How to print a date, given an instance of Date class?"

Answer (score -10, accepted):

You could use substring like so

```
String date = yourString.substring(0, 10);
```

This would pull all the characters from 0 to 10 in your String and save it as a new String.

In this case that would return "2017-04-26"

Comment: Thank you it worked, but what if I wanted to retrieve only the time? How do i count the string position?

Comment: @G.Doe Look for my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43639715/1289932

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61380425/11833795) is a proper way to do it.

Answer (score 35):

You can always use Java's `DateFormat` API for achieving this. Here is the code snippet that will help you to achieve whatever task you are looking for.

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
 Date date = dateFormat.parse("2017-04-26T20:55:00.000Z");//You will get date object relative to server/client timezone wherever it is parsed
 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); //If you need time just put specific format for time like 'HH:mm:ss'
 String dateStr = formatter.format(date);
```

You will get date object from which you can use it whichever way you would like to display using date formatter to format again.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque My answer is according to Android where Java8 support is not yet fully there. `java.time` classes are only available after `Android platform version O`. Find here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000997/android-n-java8-java-time

Comment: I should have mentioned… Much of the java.time  functionality is back-ported to a Java 6 and Java 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, a project led by the same man who led both Joda-time and java.time, Stephen Colebourne. Further adapted for Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the cleanest way to do it :

- extract the date as described here : [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)
- create a string containing the formatted date you want thanks to another DateFormat
- display it!

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.