# How to convert "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ" to "yyyy-MM-dd" without add one day in Android?

Tags: android, date, kotlin

I am develop in Android

The day of String is **2020-04-23T23:59:59-04:00**

And try to use the following function to convert the time to **2020-04-23**

```
fun changeDateFormat(strDate:String):String {
    return SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ").parse(strDate))
}
```

But it show **2020-04-24**

Did I missing something ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Wun are you sure your date has a -04:00 and not -0400?

Comment: @Kartik  Yes, I am sure

Comment: I ran your code and found an error in the time you have provided which threw parse exception for the time you shared. I made the change to the time removing the colon from -04:00 and it worked.

Comment: @Kartik I have try to removing the colon, but it is not working

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `DateTimeFormatter` and `LocalDate` from `java.time`.

for example

```
val timestampAsDateString = "2020-04-23T23:59:59-04:00"
val format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ")

val date = LocalDate.parse(timestampAsDateString, format)

Log.d("parseTesting","Date : ${date}") // logs 2020-04-23
```

since `LocalDate` is a date without time-zone in the `ISO-8601` calendar system the output is already in `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can achieve it

```
val dateInString = "2020-04-23T23:59:59-0400"
val ldt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateInString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"))
val currentZoneId: ZoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault()
val currentZonedDateTime: ZonedDateTime = ldt.atZone(currentZoneId)
val format: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
val formattedDate = format.format(currentZonedDateTime)
println(formattedDate)
```

Comment: Good answer. Still easier, the formats are built in, so you need not write any format pattern strings yourself: `OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-04-23T23:59:59-04:00").format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your time must not contain colon in between(-04:00)

This worked out well for me and returned the desired result

```
fun changeDateFormat(strDate:String):String {
    val sourceSdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.getDefault())
    val requiredSdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault())
    return requiredSdf.format(sourceSdf.parse(strDate))
}
```

Comment: I have try your code, and set the strDate = 2020-04-23T23:59:59-0400, but it return 2020-04-24

Comment: Might be related to the current timezone you are in

Answer (score 0):

I solved with :

```
val dateFormat1: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
                val dateFormat2: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                val datep: Date = dateFormat1.parse(date)
                val datei = dateFormat2.format(datep)
                val dateconverted = LocalDate.parse(datei.toString(), ISO_DATE)
```