# AS 2.3.3, Gradle 3.3, Java 1.8 Can't resolve import for java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, import

I want to do date and time safely, so I followed several pieces of SO advice saying to use `DateTimeFormatter`, so I pasted in 3 lines:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
String text = date.format(formatter);
LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(text, formatter);
```

Not surprisingly I got `Cannot resolve symbol...` for just about everything. Been there, done that. Put cursor on error routine and hit `Alt+Enter` and the proper `import` will be generated.

But that didn't happen.

So I inserted these two lines as in another sample code snippet:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

Error: `Cannot resolve symbol LocalTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`
```

My question is: **What should I do to resolve the symbols causing the error.**

I'll go on. I'm submitting more because usually when I intend to submit a Question, I figure it out my own Answer during the process of explaining what I intended to submit.

Not this time.

(Why do I have

`C:\Users\Dov\AppData\Local\Android\sdk` and

`C:\Users\Dov\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1`?

It doesn't matter which I select for SDK manager. Both are up-to-date, it says.

{I know this is gonna be embarrassing. I've been doing this too long (maybe I should stop here) for this to be holding me back. }

---

I have checked `Use embedded jdk`.

I looked at every Setting I can think of.

I've Googled the error message.

I've done `Clean` (no errors) and `Build`.

`import static...` changes nothing.

I'm using `Java 8, version 51, Android Studio 2.3.3, gradle-3.3`

Gradle console says:

```
C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\WordyHelperton - Copy - Copy
  \app\src\main\java\com\dslomer64\servyhelperton\Utilities.

java:9: error: package java.time.format does not exist
```

And:

```
C:\Users\Dov\Google Drive\AndroidStudioProjects\WordyHelperton - Copy - Copy
  \app\src\main\java\com\dslomer64\servyhelperton\Utilities.

java:321: error: cannot find symbol
```

I have this:

[image]

And this:

package java.time.format;

```
public final class DateTimeFormatter {
  private final java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder.CompositePrinterParser printerParser;
  private final java.util.Locale locale;
  private final java.time.format.DecimalStyle decimalStyle;
  private final java.time.format.ResolverStyle resolverStyle;
  private final java.util.Set<java.time.temporal.TemporalField> resolverFields;
  private final java.time.chrono.Chronology chrono;
  private final java.time.ZoneId zone;
  public static final java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter ISO_LOCAL_DATE;
  ...
```

Comment: what is your minsdkversion?

Comment: Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for Android in the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36000997/642706) project; see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While working with Android, you are using Android SDK, not JDK directly. And support for both Android SDK's [LocalTime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXab5.png) and [DateTimeFormatter](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html) added in API Level 26.

Even if you try to access these directly through JDK8, as of September 8th 2017, Android Studio has yet to support all Java 8 features. Even with the forthcoming 3.0 Preview 1, you'll only get support for following Java 8 APIs and that with minsdkversion dependency restriction as shown below.

[image]

Source: [Supported Java 8 Language Features and APIs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html)

So, as there is no mention of `java.time.*` API yet, trying to import it through JDK8 won't work as of Android Studio 3.0 Preview 1.

Comment: So were all the suggestions to use `DateTimeFormatter` from people using Eclipse?

Comment: Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for Android in the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36000997/642706) project; see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Here's a good link to follow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/2737933

Answer (score 0):

LocalTime and LocalDate are new to java 1.8.  It looks like you are using 1.7 or earlier.  You need to update your JDK to java 1.8

Comment: I've been using 1.8 for two years.