# DateTimeFormatter is not working in Android versions lower than 8

Tags: java, android, date, time, java-time

I want to subtract 30 minutes from another time string, but I am getting this error on lower versions such as  `0.5,0.6,0.7` (Lollipop, Marshmallow, Naught).
Error is as below:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/format/DateTimeFormatter;

Comment: Please post your code block, what you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android N Java8 java.time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000997/android-n-java8-java-time)

Comment: java.time is built-in from API level 26 (Oreo). There is a backport for lower levels, [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). Please consider it. More in this Stack Overflow question: [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 7):

I **solved** this issue by adding these lines in Module level build.gradle file

This happens because of Java.time was added in api level 26 so below 26 throws an error in app.

**Just add below lines**

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        // Required when setting minSdkVersion to 20 or lower
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
}
```

make sure that  **multiDexEnabled true** in both release and debug

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions. This is going to be helpful for many.